# Search for value from command output and just print that found value

Tags: regex, perl

I am calling my programm from perl and getting the output with:

```
$output = `$calling 2>>bla.txt`;
```

Now I need just a specific value that will be presented in the output which I can check with Regex.
The needed output is:

> Distance from Segment XY to its Centroid is: 3.455564713591596

Where XY is any number, and I just match for the "to its Centroid is: " the following:

```
if( $output =~ m/\sto\sits\sCentroid\sis:\s(\d)*$/)
```

But how do I get only the value that is presented near to the end? 
I just want it to be printed on the screen.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You print the number you captured in the regex with the parentheses:

```
print "$1\n" if ($output =~ m/\sto\sits\sCentroid\sis:\s([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)$/);
```

You also make sure that the regex can pick up a number with a decimal point, and I've allowed an optional sign, too.  If you need to worry about optional exponents, add `(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?` after the `\d+` in my regex.

If you have other things to do with the value, then convert into a regular `if` statement:

```
if ($output =~ m/\sto\sits\sCentroid\sis:\s([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)$/)
{
    print "$1\n";
    process_centroid($1);
}
```

Comment: it says: Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\sto\sits\sCentroid\sis:\s([-+]?\d*\.?\d+* <-- HERE )$/

Comment: +1 for the decimal point. I've shamelessly stolen that for my own answer. ;-)

Comment: (By the way, the optional sign seems unnecessary to me: we've already seen that a positive value doesn't have a sign, and one hopes that the distance is never negative!)

Comment: @Stefan: It looks like you didn't copy and paste properly. The answer's regex ends in `\d+)$`, but the regex in your error-message ends in `\d+*)$` (with an extra asterisk). The "nested quantifiers" are the stacked-up `+*`.

Comment: The first edition of the answer ended `\d+*`; I noticed it and removed the `*` without previously commenting on it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `\d*` ("zero or more digits"), you probably need to match `\d+([.]\d+)?` ("one or more digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and one or more additional digits"). That would give you:

```
if( $output =~ m/\sto\sits\sCentroid\sis:\s\d+([.]\d+)?$/)
```

(hat-tip to Jonathan Leffler for pointing that out).

That done — you want to capture the `\d+([.]\d+)?`, so, wrap it in parentheses to create a capture-group:

```
if( $output =~ m/\sto\sits\sCentroid\sis:\s(\d+([.]\d+)?)$/)
```

and then the special variable `$1` will be whatever it captured:

```
if( $output =~ m/\sto\sits\sCentroid\sis:\s(\d+([.]\d+)?)$/)
    { print $1; }
```

See [the "Extracting matches" section of the `perlretut` ("Perl regular expressions tutorial") manual-page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches).

By the way, `\s` matches a single white-space character. Usually you'd want either to match only an actual space — write e.g. `to its` rather than `to\sits` — or to match one *or more* white-space characters — e.g. `to\s+its`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks! You were actually commenting just as I was editing *my* answer due to having seen *your* answer. :-P